# how to loop through 5,000 Twitter users to grab the bio / description

Tags: php, twitter

I have a text file with 5,000 Twitter Users :-

```
JRJSHEARD
KMM_1979
ELMOCHLOE
ANNIEMMERSON
PATLOCKLEY
LISSYNUMBER
CAL32INCHSCREEN
PRINGLEDUDE
CORESMUSIC
```

I have found this API http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.xml?screen_name=JRJSHEARD which is really useful and just what I need.

How would I write a php function to loop through the user names in a text file and append their bio found between these tags (`<description> </description>)`.

Is this possible? Any help would be gratefully received.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a suspicious thing to want to do at all.

Comment: What are you having trouble with? Looping over the user names? Calling the API? Parsing the API response? Appending their bio?

Comment: all of the above. It may seem suspicious but I'm simply trying to profile twitter users who have tweeted a specific keyword and then create a word cloud of their bios to see if there is some interesting insights

Answer (score 2):

If you want to harvest user info in bulk from Twitter use *[users/lookup](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/users/lookup)* rather than *users/show*.  The *users/lookup* API call returns 100 user objects at a time, and you can either pass the user IDs or the screen names when you make the call, however you will need to authenticate using OAuth in order to use it.

I recommend using JSON since it is a much more lightweight document format than XML. You will typically transfer only about 1/3 to 1/2 as much data over the wire, and I find that (in my experience) Twitter times-out less often when serving JSON.

```
http://api.twitter.com/1/users/lookup.json?screen_name=JRJSHEARD,KMM_1979,ELMOCHLOE
```

That's the direct API call, but if you're just starting out, what I would recommend is using a Twitter service implementation rather than try to do all the heavy lifting yourself.  I'm not a PHP person, but my PHP-using Twitter buddies recommend Zend - http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.service.twitter.html

Comment: This is outdated and does not work anymore. Returned message:

```json
{"errors":[{"message":"The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to API v1.1. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview.","code":64}]}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$api = "http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.xml?screen_name=";

$users = file("users.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

$i = 0;
foreach($users as $user){
    $data = curl("$api$user");
    preg_match("#<description>(.*?)</description>#is", $data, $matches);
    $bio[$i]["user"] = $user;
    $bio[$i]["description"] = $matches[1];
$i++;
}

function curl($url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_close($ch);
    return curl_exec($ch);
}
```

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a go. Yes I am trying to get some 'free code', it's to get an idea of where to start because I am a novice.

Comment: You should do it by chunks, eg. 100 requests a time, with 2s pause `sleep(2)`, then insert data from `$bio` to database. Pause a little then again for next 100. You should set `set_time_limit(0);` else you will receive error 500.